# Saving to CoreData while looping through a array

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I get the this string `"85:ABC ,83:CFD"` after downloading from a web service.I need to store these values to CoreData table TABLE_JOBTITLE. I have the below code

```
var designationDictionaryArray = results.componentsSeparatedByString(",")

var index: Int = 1
        for item in designationDictionaryArray
        {
            let appDelegate =
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

            let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext


            let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("TABLE_JOBTITLE",
                                                            inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

            let job = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,
                                      insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

            job.setValue(String(index), forKey: "column_Id")
            job.setValue(String(item.componentsSeparatedByString(":")[0]), forKey: "column_Server_Id")
            job.setValue(String(item.componentsSeparatedByString(":")[1]), forKey: "column_Job_Name")

            print("Column_Id")
            print(index)
            print("Column_Server_Id")
            print(String(item.componentsSeparatedByString(":")[0]))
            print("column_Job_Name")
            print(String(item.componentsSeparatedByString(":")[1]))


            do {
                try managedContext.save()
                print("saved job title")
            } catch let error as NSError  {
                print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }

            self.desiginationArray.append(item.componentsSeparatedByString(":")[1])
            index = index + 1
        }
```

I am able to iterate through each data but the when i store it in the table..It get stored like below

```
coulmn_Id          column_ServerId    column_Job_Title              
1                        83                  CFD
1                        83                  CFD
```

Could anyone help me with corrected code or reason for this bizarre behavior please..

Comment: is this actually copy&paste, because various names don't match? how are you testing this and querying the data back after is should be saved? consider what actually needs to be in the loop, like do you need to get the app delegate and context each time through the loop??

Comment: no its not copy paste.. I wrote the code...sorry i was in a hurry to post the question...I fetched all data from the table and tested..no the app delegate and managed context need not be inside the for loop...I tried placing it inside for loop to test and see whether it fixes the problem or not

Comment: Apart from the issue, do not save the context in each iteration of the loop, this is very inefficient. And it seems that the received string is separated by `space-comma` while you're separating only by `comma`.

Comment: You should save the managedContext outside of the scope of the loop, even put your local vars, appDelegate and managedContext outside the loop scope.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect one of two things:

1. The value in result is not as you expect.
2. The manner in which you are checking the output is faulty.

I lean towards the latter as I do not see any way both entities could be assigned the same column ID in a single run through.

Put breakpoints up top to check the value of results and the array returned from `results.componentsSeparatedByString(",")`.

Show the code you used to iterate through the table to check it. My bet is that you are not showing the true output. What is the output from the print lines within the loop? If it looks something like this:

```
Column_Id
1
Column_Server_Id
85
column_Job_Name
ABC
Column_ID
2
Column_Server_ID
83
Column_ID
CFD
```

Then I'd say, for sure, you are not properly reading back your results from Core Data. Let us see where you are getting that final table.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the problem was the same code worked as it should.